# How to add dependency to PNPM workspace?

Tags: node.js, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

I start using PNPM Workspaces, and I'm struggling in how to add dependencies to any specific workspace as I would do in yarn running:

```
yarn workspace <workspace_name> add <package_to_add>
```

Or even running scripts for specific packages as I would do in yarn like:

```
yarn workspace <workspace_name> run <script>
```

How is the PNPM community doing this? You really need to go to the workspace `package.json` file and add it manually?

*Been a while searching for docs without success*

Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

So I found an answer and is using the `--filter` option.

i.e.

```sh
# Using the exact package name
pnpm add <package_to_add> --filter <workspace_name>
# Or using a pattern
pnpm add <package_to_add> --filter <prefix>/*
```

Same for run, etc...